# Creating formatted String (including floats) in Arduino-compatible C++

Tags: c++, string

I'm using a Mega2560 and a generic SSD1306 OLED display with the Adafruit_SSD1306 (and by extension, Adafruit_gfx) library.

I need to print a bunch of float values (ranging between 30.0 and 99.9) to the display with exactly one decimal place of precision. The catch is, the Adafruit library doesn't have a printf() method, only one that takes a single ready-to-print string.

Here's an (obviously non-Arduino) Java-like example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
String foo = String.format("%.1f, %.1f\%", temp1, hum1);
// "display" is my instance of Adafruit_SSD1306
display.print(foo);
```

So... how can I do something similar in Arduino-compatible C(++)?

Note: for this specific program, I have (relatively speaking) RAM to burn, so I really don't care if whatever library I use to generate formatted Strings is particularly efficient (as long as it isn't leaking). If it wants to use 4k of RAM and 80k of flash to format a 20-character String, so be it.

Comment: use dtostrf() function

Answer (score 4):

Normally for formatting strings I'd suggest the venerable `snprintf` and similar functions. However, on an 8-bit Arduino when you're using floats that's not an option: the function that does all the formatting for this family if functions has had floating point support surgically removed from it. This is to make the function a fraction of the size so it's not as bloaty in small microcontrollers.

I believe there is a float-capable version somewhere on the internet that could be somehow installed, though I have never looked into doing that.

Instead you need to do the formatting of floats manually.  Everything else can be done with `snprintf`, but the floats need to be done separately.

Fortunately there's a function specifically for formatting a float into a character array (C-string), called `dtostrf` and is used thus:

```
float myVal = 23.49173783;
char *buffer[10]; // Enough room for the digits you want and more to be safe
dtostrf(myVal, 9, 1, buffer);
```

The first number in the parameter list is how many characters you want to have in your output, including the `.` and any leading `-`. Any extra characters are padded with space.  The second number is how many decimal places.  If the first number is negative the value is left-aligned. If it's positive it's right-aligned.  So the code above would give you:

```
〿〿〿〿〿23.5␀
```

(Note: I am using `〿` to denote a space character.) If you used `-9` you'd get:

```
23.5〿〿〿〿〿␀
```

You can, of course, feed that created string into another string using `snprintf` and the `%s` placeholder.

```
char buf2[32];
snprintf(buf2, 32, "The temperature is: %s\r\n", buffer);

buf2 ⇒ "The temperature is: 23.5〿〿〿〿〿"
```

If you want to trim the string down to just contain the number portion and lose the spaces it's best to left-align it with a negative width, then change the first space to a `␀`:

```
char *space = strchr(buffer, ' ');
if (space != NULL) {
    *space = '\0';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `Adafruit_GFX` class has two methods named `print()` and
`println()`. These behave exactly like `Serial.print()` and
`Serial.println()`. Specifically, when printing a float, you can provide
a second argument telling it the number of decimal places you want after
the decimal point:

```
display.print(temp1, 1);  // 1 digit after the decimal point
display.print(", ");
display.print(hum1, 1);  // ditto
display.print("%");
```

**Background**: the reason these methods behave like the ones of
`Serial` is that both `Adafruit_GFX` and `HardwareSerial` inherit them
from the [`Print` virtual class](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/1.8.5/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/Print.h).

Comment: it is not ideal for right aligned float numbers on LCD

Comment: @Juraj: That's right. However, the format used by the OP in his question (`"%.1f, %.1f\%"`) doesn't do any kind of alignment. Thus I assumed that alignment is not a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

One can use the `String()` type initialization to convert any number, including float to String. For example to convert `3.14159` simply type ⤵︎

```cpp
float num = 3.14159
String str1 = String(num, 1) // 3.1
String str2 = String(num, 2) // 3.14
String str3 = String(num, 3) // 3.141
```

To the right of the comma is the number of decimal places one wants the string result to have. It has a lot of functionality but that's one of the overloads. You can see them [all here!](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference.StringConstructor)

To see this code working on a .ino sketch check out this GitHub repo
https://github.com/aeonSolutions/aeonlabs-ESP32-C-Base-Firmware-Libraries